# Setting multiple views folder for Express does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to set multiple views directory for Express. Using Express version 4.16.3, Node.js `version v10.15`., and EJS `version 2.5.9`.

```
app.set('views', [path.join(__dirname, 'views'), path.join(__dirname, 'public/static/')]);
```

Receiving this error message:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object

All help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: I am trying to setup multiple folders for my views, meaning that EJS should find them in either `views`, or `public/static` folder.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean your trying to set multiple views up?

Your passing in an array which it doesn't like.

View's should look like this:

```
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
```

and your static - what I would call your front end work should go here, css,js,images etc:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Comment: I am trying to setup multiple **folders** for views. I mean that my views are either in 'views' folder, or 'public/static' folder. As per the documentation, it should work. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set, says "A directory or an array of directories for the application's views. If an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array."